# Justified text Swiftui

Tags: swift, text, uilabel, swiftui

I found that we can align text like that :

```
.multilineTextAlignment(.center)
.multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
.multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
```

But there is no justified attribute, is there a fastest way than use a `UILabel` and `UIViewRepresentable` ?

thanks

Comment: i think you are right, you have to use UIRepresentable

Comment: thanks, SwiftUI is very powerful but he is missing stuff at the moment !